# Possibility for two distinct polynomials to interpolate the same m data points

Tags: numerical-methods

Is it ever possible for two distinct polynomials to interpolate the same m data points? If so, under what conditions, and if not, why?

Comment: Assume polynomial $p(x)$  interpolate a list of $m$ data points $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_m,y_m)$. Another polynomial $q(x)$ will interpolate same list of data points when and only when their difference $p(x) - q(x)$ is divisible by the polynomial $\prod_{k=1}^m (x - x_k)$. This means there is at most one polynomial which interpolate the data points with degree less than $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  The points $(-1, 0)$ and $(1,0)$ are interpolated by each of the two polynomials:
$$
p(x) = x^2 - 1
$$
and $-p(x)$.

There are much more interesting examples.

One of the general reasons as to why this should be possible: there is a problem of Lagrangian or Newtonian interpolation (we seek a polynomial going through the given points), but there is also the problem of [Hermitian interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation) which, in addition to the requirement of going through the given points, also requires the polynomial to have *prescribed derivatives* at these points.

So, a polynomial that solves an Hermitian interpolation problem for a given set of points also solves the Lagrangian interpolation problem for those points.  But not vice versa.